# Linux. Route through IPSec tunnel

Tags: linux, networking

I have three instances with Linux.
"Remote", "Local", "Client".
There is an IPSec tunnel between the "Remote" and "Local" ones. "Client" accesses the network through the "Local".

How can I make the "Client" get access to the internet only through the IPSec tunnel to the "Remote" machine. Using static routing or other methods?

[Example with IP Addresses:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47qhQ.jpg)

Comment: How is "Client" connected to "Local"?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding that is not possible with regular IPsec because IPsec is pure layer 3 (IP) but routing requires addressing the next hop on layer 2 (including point-to-point connections) i.e. sending an IP packet to a system which is not the one with the target IP.

This might work of you used IPsec without phase 2 configuration so that you have an interface which behaves like a regular interface so that you can use it for routing. Or you create another (non-encrypted) tunnel on top of IPsec e.g. an `ipip` interface which you can use for routing to the other side of the IPsec tunnel.